# Microsoft Interop Outlook c# - invalidcastexception?

Tags: interop, outlook, .net

Suddenly getting a System.invalidcastexception: unable to cast COM object of type 'system._object' to interface type 'Microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem' ... to a program I wrote that was working fine and now BAM! Exception.

Not sure why... please note I'm a novice programmer.

Here's a snippet of coding where I'm using the Outlook things :

```cs
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
static _NameSpace ns = null;
static MailItem item = null;
static MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
static MAPIFolder dest = null;
static void SendMail(string mailSubject, string htmlMailBody, string mailTo)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    NameSpace outlookNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    outlookNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);
    MailItem oMsg = (MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
    oMsg.To = mailTo;
    oMsg.Recipients.ResolveAll();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\" + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1] + @"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Default.htm");
    string signature = sr.ReadToEnd();
    oMsg.Subject = mailSubject;
    oMsg.HTMLBody = htmlMailBody + "<br><br>" + signature + "</font>";
    oMsg.Save();
    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)oMsg).Send();
    oMsg = null;
    outlookNS = null;
    outlookApp = null;
}

app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.Logon(null, null, false, false);
inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

#region match - convert - extract
foreach (string tifFile in Directory.GetFiles(workFolder, "*.tif", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    string currentFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tifFile);

    for (int i = 1; i <= inboxFolder.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        //##############CODE CRASHES HERE##############

        item = (MailItem)inboxFolder.Items[i];
        // item = inboxFolder.Items[i];
        if (item.Body != "")
        {
            if ((item.Body.Contains("Box Number =")) && (item.Body.Contains("Contract ID = ")) && (item.Body.Contains("Branch = ")) && (item.Body.Contains(currentFile.Replace('_', '/'))))
            {
                //    matchFound = true;
                MailStack current = new MailStack();
                Console.WriteLine("________________________");
                Console.WriteLine("File matched \t\t:\t" + currentFile + ".tif");
```

I've looked around but can't make much sense of the answers available.

any help appreciated.

Comment: There's an item in the inbox that is not a mail item.  Bam.  Use the *as* operator to cast, skip the item when you get null.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok just skimmed through my inbox there is in fact a non-mailitem item in my inbox, a meeting request.  Really? I haven't used the as operator for casting before could you give me an example please?  Thanks.

Comment: Really?  Type "c# as operator" in a google query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```cs
item = inboxFolder.Items[i] as MailItem;
if (item != null) 
{ 
   // ...
}
```